# Attendance management

Tags: c#

I want to check the login time is am or pm and give the am checkbox to true otherwise
pm is true.that is time is below 1pm the the forenoon checkbox is true otherwise afternoon checkbox

Comment: What do you have at the moment?

Comment: Hi, can you reformulate your question? ...because it does not really sound like a question.

Comment: something like: If (Datetime.Now.Hour > 12) { string time = "PM"; } else { string time = "AM"; } ...  can ofcourse be changed in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As System.DateTime implements IFormattable, you can pass in format strings to the ToString method (or when using string.Format etc). One of those format strings is "tt", and it will give you either "AM" or "PM" based on the time.

```
DateTime time = GetAfternoonTime();
Console.Writeline(time.ToString("tt")); //Prints "PM"

time = GetMorningTime();
Console.Writeline(time.ToString("tt")); //Prints "AM"
```

Now if you want to bind that to a checkbox for example:

```
myAMCheckbox.Checked = dateTime.ToString("tt") == "AM";
myPMCheckbox.Checked = dateTime.ToString("tt") == "PM";
```

That code can obviously be optimised to only do the string conversion once. Also the advantage of this method is that you can easily make it globalised by passing in CultureInfo objects.

Example of making this culture aware:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

DateTime dateTime = GetSomeDateTime();

string AMorPM = dateTime.ToString("tt", culture);

myAMCheckbox.Checked = (AMorPM == culture.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator);
myPMCheckbox.Checked = (AMorPM == culture.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator);
```